# Explain (buffers, analyse) in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, instructions

I am new in postgresql and I try to understand [explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-explain.html) (buffers, analyse) instruction. I have a query and I execute it using explain (buffers, analyse).

The first time i execute it the performance is worse than the second time. Also, the first time i get a 'read' parameter next to 'hit' while the second time the 'read' does not exist.

Can somebody help me understand?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

first time you select, pages get warm - they are loaded to cache, once they are in RAM - all next selects will be faster (RAM speed is higher).

Accordingly `buffers` show read, when pages are not in cache, cos postgres reads them, and no read when they are warm, so cache is hit...

Update with [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html):

> BUFFERS
>
> Include information on buffer usage. Specifically, include the
>   number of shared blocks hit, read, dirtied, and written, the number of
>   local blocks hit, read, dirtied, and written, and the number of temp
>   blocks read and written. A hit means that a read was avoided because
>   the block was found already in cache when needed. Shared blocks
>   contain data from regular tables and indexes; local blocks contain
>   data from temporary tables and indexes; while temp blocks contain
>   short-term working data used in sorts, hashes, Materialize plan nodes,
>   and similar cases. The number of blocks dirtied indicates the number
>   of previously unmodified blocks that were changed by this query; while
>   the number of blocks written indicates the number of
>   previously-dirtied blocks evicted from cache by this backend during
>   query processing. The number of blocks shown for an upper-level node
>   includes those used by all its child nodes. In text format, only
>   non-zero values are printed. This parameter may only be used when
>   ANALYZE is also enabled. It defaults to FALSE.

And surprisingly not much about buffers [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html).