# How can I get space consumed by a queryset using Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

Suppose I make a query like -
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE condition

I want to know how much disk space this queryset has consumed.

Comment: Did you try `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE condition ` ?

Comment: Yes I tried it but I do not get the space

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `explain (analyze,buffers) SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE condition` that will give you information on all the blocks that were used, the temp ones show the direct usage by the query. You can get a little more information [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43887275/explain-buffers-analyse-in-postgresql)